# How to Write HTML in javascript with new line (\n) option

Tags: javascript

I have large HTML to be generated dynamically through javascript so the reason i dont want it be in a single line

I was trying it as this way but getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL under browser console

```
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
    divhtml.append('<li>
        <h6>'+response[i].RestaurantName+'</h6>\n
        <p>'+response[i].Locality+'</p>\n
        </li>');
}
```

Please see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/eb1t5jop/3/

Answer (score 1):

You put a backslash at the end of the line just before the newline:

```
for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
{
    divhtml.append('<li>\
        <h6>'+response[i].RestaurantName+'</h6>\
        <p>'+response[i].Locality+'</p>\
        </li>');
}
```

This is covered in [§7.8.4 - *String Literals*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4) in the spec (see *LineContinuation*).

Note that:

- The escaped newline will *not* be in the string; if you want a newline (unnecessary in HTML where you have those `\n`s), include a `\n` prior to the `\` at the end of the line.
- Leading spaces on subsequent lines *will* be in the string